# Randomly generate pdf on website

Tags: html, scripts, random, latex2html

I have created a latex file which creates a pdf by randomly selecting 10 subfiles from a pool of files. This works fine, and I am able to generate a random PDF every time I run my script. A breakdown of how this works:

(within a latex article)

Generate random number.

Use this number to include a subfile.

Repeat this for 10 times without repeating the random generated number.

**HOWEVER**, I now would like to implement this into my website. I would like a user of my websit to "press a button", this runs the script and spits out a PDF for them to download. Any ideas how I might be able to achieve this?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: This isn't really a TeX question. I think you want to tell your server to run TeX. That may run into security problems. Perhaps ask on stackoverflow. If you get an answer I'd be interested. (You can find me from my profile here).

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure this question is related to LaTeX. Try http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies.

@Clément, I will definitely have a look at serverfault. I might have to move away from TeX though. Don't really want to do that as I already have my PDF nicely typeset.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I will keep you posted on what I end up doing. I did read a post on texexchange about security problems when running latex online. However, I wanted to know if maybe there was someone who came up of a cheeky work around or something.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I came across this website: http://www.mathmaster.org/dotevenodd/ . It seems to be running latex through Python, and the generated pdf is of top notch quality.

I will be pursing this further.